# Do star fragments wash up for specific players or everyone?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-horizons

On the night of a meteor shower, if multiple players make wishes on shooting stars, do the star fragments wash up the next day for each player according to how many they saw, or do they wash up for all players?

In other words, say Player 1 wishes on 5 stars, Player 2 wishes on 10 stars. The next day, star fragments will wash up on the shore. If Player 1 plays first, could they potentially get all 15 star fragments? or will only their 5 fragments wash up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually experimented on this with a few friends.

1. Wishes are returned to your own island (go to a friend's island and wish, the fragments will appear on your island the next day)
2. Local play doesn't care who made the wish, it all goes to the same island (I believe this is your main question)
3. There is no limit to the number of wishes you can make
4. Not every wish will generate a star fragment the next day, it is kind of a diminishing return system. (as you wish on more stars, the number of fragments you get doesn't increase as much). I've yet to find a hard cap on star fragments, though.
5. If you made a lot of wishes during the night, the beach will spawn star fragments all day until your count is fulfilled. (I had a big star shower one night, getting well over 200 wishes. and a total of 73 fragments was added to my storage by day end.)

Answer (score 3):

Star shards are treated like sea shells. They are character independent, and can even be picked up by visitors from other islands.